# How to remove black area above my app after Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode11.2.1

My app was working fine until iOS 13 I faced new issues in the UI top portion.

First the screens became as Cards and I changed the ViewController `Presentation` to `Full Screen` and my segues `Kind` to `Present Modally` and `Presentation` to `Full Screen`

However I am still having **blank** **black** area above my app's screen.

App Screen in Simulator:

[image]

App Screen in Simulator:

[image]

App Screen in Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Does your app include a launch storyboard?  If you are still using launch images you either need to include all device size images or (highly recommended) adopt a launch storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out this issues on `Xcode 11`. Please flow this below steps:

1. If you are using launch screen and launch screen not added on your project, then add new `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file. Add a launch screen `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file to your project. (File -> New -> File... -> Launch Screen)

[image]

2. Now choose your project name in Xcode. -> Select your project target -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch Screen File: `LaunchScreen.storyboard`

[image]